# How can I share a common sidebar navigation in all ASP.NET MVC areas

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC 5, and I'm trying to build several areas that all have the same sidebar navigation menu (the navigation is a simple bootstrap component, no server-side logic). So depending on the area, a different item in the navigation bar should be made active.
This all works great when I only use one root area.

But how can I share the same navigation menu in all areas? I understand that there is usually a ~/Views/_Viewstart.cshtml file for the root area, which points to a common (shared) /Shared/_Layout.cshtml. I would like to use a common layout for all areas.

So the areas are:
 - (root)/empty for the welcome page/main page
 - Setup area
 - Sales area
 - Inventory area

So the sidebar nvigation contains those for links. The sidebar should always be visible in all areas.

**What is the correct way of accomplishing that?**

Comment: Create a CustomLayout which will contain only your sidemenu bar and inherit your main layout inside this customlayout..
In your views you can use this CustomLayout where you want sidemenu, for rest of the views you can use the default layout

Answer (score 0):

Use partial view to render your navigation menu. To make your partial view accessible from all areas, put it into "**~\Views\Shared**" (please note, it is **not** an area specific folder).